# Iterate over status bar notification elements

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-maps-v2

How can I iterate over status bar notification elements? I'm using `NotificationListenerService`. I want to do this to get the direction icon/picture.

I already tried `sbn.getNotification().getSmallIcon()`, `sbn.getNotification().extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)` and `sbn.getNotification().getLargeIcon()` but I'm not able to get the picture/icon

I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

[image]

Comment: Notice how the notification doesn't align with how other notifications look - this is most likely a [custom content view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)), and it has an `ImageView` as one of the components in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. It'd be a privacy issue if your app was allowed to see / view / read notification elements from other applications.